# How to pass an html page in json request body?

Tags: jmeter

I'm using `${__FileToString(page_source.txt,,)}` to read an HTML page and passing this function as a value for a key in JSON payload. The problem is that the HTML page has multiple " and spaces, due to which the target server is giving a response `'Failed to decode JSON object'`. This is happening as the " and spaces are getting creating problems in being passed as a JSON.

How can I pass the HTML page as the value of a JSON payload key?

Answer (score 0):

If your `page_source.txt` file contains characters which needs to be [escaped](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html) you need to use i.e. __groovy() function and call appropriate [StringEscapeUtils](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/StringEscapeUtils.html) class method, something like:

```
${__groovy(groovy.json.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(new File('page_source.txt').text),)}
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting groovy. I used
def jsonString = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(request) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

${__FileToString(page_source.txt,,)} function give back String not JSON object.
You need to pre-process String obtained from FileToString function before passing on as JSON object.
Things you can do:

1. convert string to Json object before passing on further. I don't think this should be requisite input for function expecting json object.
2. Extract specific string or key value pairs from from the output of FileToString function